# Bug in LC-3 assembly code-finding maximum number in list

Tags: assembly, lc3

There's a bug in my code that's supposed to find the largest value in a list of non-negative numbers and put that value in R5. The memory location of the beginning of the list is in R2, and the end of the list of numbers is signified by a negative value. That is, if R2=x4000, and the contents of memory are: x4000 =5, x4001=1, x4002=-1, then the value 5 should be placed in R5. But there's a bug that prevents this from happening. 
My professor said I only need to add a **single line** somewhere for it to work.
Any help is appreciated!

Here is my assembly code:

```
.ORIG x3000

SETUP LEA R2, DATA ; set R2    
START AND R5,R5,#0
LOOP LDR R3,R2,#0
ADD R2,R2,#1
NOT R4,R5
ADD R4,R4,#1    
ADD R4,R3,R4
BRn LOOP
ADD R5,R3,#0
BRnzp LOOP ;loop
QUIT HALT

DATA .FILL #6
.FILL #8
.FILL #11
.FILL #2
.FILL #0
.FILL #5
.FILL #-4
.END
```

Comment: So you have come here to ask us to do it for you? Maybe tell your professor you need more explanation. He gets paid for teaching you...

Comment: I came here for help

Answer (score 1):

```
.ORIG x3000

SETUP LEA R2, DATA ; set R2    
START AND R5,R5,#0  
LOOP LDR R3,R2,#0   
**BRn QUIT  ;Ends the loop once the list has a negative number in it**  
ADD R2,R2,#1   
NOT R4,R5   
ADD R4,R4,#1    
ADD R4,R3,R4  
BRn LOOP  
ADD R5,R3,#0  
BRnzp LOOP ;loop  
QUIT HALT

DATA .FILL #6  
.FILL #8  
.FILL #11  
.FILL #2  
.FILL #0  
.FILL #5  
.FILL #-4  
.END
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the ASSM you are programming in, following is PSEUSO code ASSM (the last time I wrote ASSM was in 1991):

```
BEGIN:
  MOV AX,R2 // Start of data
  MOV BX,-1 // Initial value
START:
  PEEK AX,CX // Get 1st location to CX
  CMP CX,0 // Compare with zero
  JMP_LESS END // End of list reached
  CMP CX,BX
  JMP_GT ASSIGN // Do the assign
  INC AX // Next address
  JMP START:
ASSIGN:
  MOV BX,CX // BX now has the bigger #
  INC AX // Next address
  JMP START
END:
  # Do stuff with highest #
  # Do cleanup
LIST:
8
11
5
-4
```

Hopefully it will give you an idea where your problem is.

Comment: your `peek` instruction has the destination on the right, but all the regular x86 instructions you used have the destination on the left.  That's super weird.  Use `mov cx, [ax]`, or `load cx, [ax]` if you want to make up mnemonics.

Comment: This helped me figure it out! I knew I had to break the loop when the listed number was negative but I was overthinking it too much. Just had to add a break to quit when R3 was negative. Super easy

Comment: Just to give an idea to the person asking the question (PSEUDO CODE)... I wrote an entire operating system during 1988 to 1991 in Z80, MC68008 and 386. This is not a 'get browny points' (win the programmer of the year award, etc thing, just trying to help someone out figure out a problem.